# Proof idea: $S_3 \cong D_3$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I am trying to show that $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$ as groups. The definitions I'm working with are
$$
S_3 = \left \langle (12), (123) \right \rangle, \; D_3 = \left \langle r, s \mid r^3 = s^2 = 1, \; sr = r^{-1} s\right \rangle.
$$
My thought process is that I can map generators to generators. So I can send $(12) \to s$ and $(123) \to r$, where $s$ is some reflection and $r$ a counterclockwise rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ radians. If I define such a map $\phi: S_3 \to D_3$, I can show that $(12)$ and $(123)$ satisfy the same defining relations as $D_3$. I believe that gives the homomorphism property, but I'm not completely sure how to show that is a bijection of sets. I'd like to write an element of $S_3$ in the form $(12)^i (123)^j$ for $i \in \{0,1\}$ and $j \in \{0,1,2\}$, but this won't work for every element because I may need to swap the order; if I allow inverses, I think this may work. Then I'd apply $\phi$ and need to show that every element of $D_3$ is accounted for exactly once. In fact, since, as sets, both $S_3$ and $D_3$ have the same order, I'd only need to check one of injectivity or surjectivity.

My main questions are:

1. Is it enough, for a homomorphism, to check that the image of $S_3$ under $\phi$ satisfy the same defining relations?
2. How can I formalize the notion of $(12)$ and $(123)$ generating $S_3$ in order to show that $\phi$ is bijective? Is the idea that I have in mind on the right track, and would it work if I allow $i$ and $j$ to be negative?

Comment: You don't need to swap order. Every element of $S_3$ has a unique expression as $(12)^i(123)^j$.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki What would $i$ and $j$ range over, though? And is this a fact that is just true for $S_3$, or is it true in general for groups that are generated by multiple elements?

Comment: As you stated, $i\in\{0,1\}$ and $j\in\{0,1,2\}$. Since $S_3$ has only six elements, you can just compute the six products. In general, groups generated by two elements can be arbitrarily complicated (even infinite). So one cannot expect writing elements in $\langle x,y\rangle$ as $x^iy^j$.

Comment: For example that sporadic monster group of order 808,017,424,794,512,875,886,459,904,961,710,757,005,754,368,000,000,000 is generated by elements $x,y$ of order 2 and 3 respectively. So there are only six elements of the form $x^iy^j$.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki This is extremely helpful. Thank you. In general, though, is it enough to check that the image of the generators satisfies the defining relations? I'm still struggling to piece together the argument for an isomorphism.

Comment: There is a theorem of von Dyck saying: If G and H are groups with the "same" generators such that the defining relations of G are true in H, then there exists an epimorphism $G\to H$ (this is a consequence of the universal property of free groups). In your case it must be an isomorphism since $|G|=|H|$.

Comment: The von Dyck Theorem gives a homomorphism $D_3 \to S_3$ not (as stated in the post) $S_3 \to D_3$).

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.